# PHP With 2 arrays how do I get first element that exists in both arrays based on the order of the first array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I'm trying to compare two arrays to get the first element that exists in both arrays.  I thought I could use array_intersect to do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a representative example of my code.

```
<?php
$a1=array(
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>ZPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'));
$a2=array(
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
    new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>NONE</LabelSize><LabelFormat>NONE</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>')
);

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

This gives me the output

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [LabelSize] => 6 [LabelFormat] => ZPL ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [LabelSize] => 6 [LabelFormat] => EPL ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [LabelSize] => 6 [LabelFormat] => PNG ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [LabelSize] => 6 [LabelFormat] => JPG ) )
```

As you can see, the first element from `$a1` exists in the intersection even though it does NOT exist in `$a2`.

Comment: One loop nested within another will do it. Or Have you tried leaving the elements of the arrays as strings and only creating a SimpleXMLElement after finding the intersection?

Comment: I get both arrays as XML elements from a web service.  I was hoping to avoid nested loops for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal, because it is just comparing if it is the same type of object.

You have two options :

1. Change the parameters you are using by comparing string instead of simpleXMLElement with the array_intersect function. Not recommended, because you are not comparing the actual values of each xml node.

```php
<?php
$a1=array(
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>ZPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'));
$a2=array(
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        ('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>NONE</LabelSize><LabelFormat>NONE</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>')
        );

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

This will return :

```php
Array
(
    [1] => <LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>
    [2] => <LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>
    [3] => <LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>
)
```

2. Write a custom function to match the values of the node using the desired logic. That's a better solution.

```php
   $a1 = array(
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>ZPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'));

    $a2 = array(
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>EPL</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>8</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>6</LabelSize><LabelFormat>JPG</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>'),
        new SimpleXMLElement('<LabelSpec><LabelSize>NONE</LabelSize><LabelFormat>NONE</LabelFormat></LabelSpec>')
    );

    function customIntersect($arr1, $arr2)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($arr1 as $simplexml1) 
        {
            foreach ($arr2 as $simplexml2) 
            {
                // Your custom comparison logic should be here ...
                if (((string) $simplexml1->LabelSize == (string) $simplexml2->LabelSize) && 
                    ((string) $simplexml1->LabelFormat == (string) $simplexml2->LabelFormat))
                {
                    $result[] = $simplexml1;
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    print_r(customIntersect($a1, $a2));
```

Will return :

```php
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [LabelSize] => 6
            [LabelFormat] => EPL
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [LabelSize] => 6
            [LabelFormat] => PNG
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [LabelSize] => 6
            [LabelFormat] => JPG
        )

)
```

Comment: I went with option 1 in the end as it was easier to just call `$simpleXml->asXML()` than to use the loop.  Thanks